# Is using an 'include wrapper' considered bad practice/indicative of bad design?

Tags: c++, include

Consider a situation where you are tasked with writing a simple pretty-printing facility for the standard library containers. In a header `pretty_print.hpp` you declare the following functions:

```
// In pretty_print.hpp
template<typename T>
void pretty_print(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& vec);

template<typename T>
void pretty_print(std::ostream& os, std::set<T> const& set);

template<typename T, typename U>
void pretty_print(std::ostream& os, std::map<T, U> const& map);

// etc.
```

However, as the containers cannot be forward declared, you must `#include` each of the container headers. As a result, including `pretty_print.hpp` into other parts of your library would (could?) cause quite a lot of code bloat. So, in a way to avoid introducing these dependencies into other compilation units, you make a bunch of files (I’m calling them 'header wrappers' because I couldn't find any other terminology) called `print_vector.hpp`, `print_set.hpp`, etc. that all have a similar layout:

```
// In print_vector.hpp
#include <vector>
template<typename T>
void pretty_print(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& vec);

// In print_set.hpp
#include <set>
template<typename T>
void pretty_print(std::ostream& os, std::set<T> const& set);

// you get the point
```

So when you want to be able to `pretty_print` a vector, you'd `#include print_vector.hpp` and it would only introduce `<vector>` into the current compilation unit and not `<set>`, `<map>` or any other header you mightn't need. Note that I’m using `pretty_print` as an example (I’m sure there are far superior ways to pretty print containers) but there are other reasons you might want to do this (for example making a `lean_windows.h` header 'wrapper' where you `#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` before including `windows.h`).

I can't see anything wrong with this approach as it means you are avoiding the potential bloat caused introducing a bunch of headers you may not use/need in a compilation unit. Despite this, it still feels 'wrong' in the sense that it may not be apparent to others your 'include wrapper' actually includes the header you intended, and seems to tarnish the 'sanctity' of including standard library headers (`#include <string>` is idiomatic, whereas `#include "string_wrapper.hpp"` is not).

Is this considered bad practice\indicative of bad design?

Comment: In this example, I don't think you (or your users) should think of `print_vector.hpp` as being a wrapper for `<vector>`. As it happens, it does include `<vector>`, but that's not what it's actually *for*, it's for declaring an overload of `pretty_print`. If there were a `<vectorfwd>` analogous to `<iosfwd>` then it would include that instead, likewise if you came up with a (non-portable) way to forward-declare `vector` on a particular implementation then you could optimize `print_vector` for that implementation. Generally users shouldn't rely on transitive includes.

Comment: Including `<vector>` will not introduce any extra code in your program ("code bloat"), all it potentially does is increase the time it takes to compile each .cpp file.

Comment: @SteveJessop: you are correct about my terminology, and perhaps the example I used wasn't the best. If I was including a large library header that had some compilation 'options' (such as `WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN` or `NOMINMAX` for `windows.h`) would it be okay to wrap only the `#define`s and `#include` in a header as long as it wasn't used in files exposed to the user? @Bo: yes, you are correct. I am not 100% savvy on the consequences of including many template headers but from the general jist of what I have read I know it should be avoided where possible. I guess I have a lot of reading to do.

Comment: @AndrewH: the trouble with those compilation options is that whatever header includes `windows.h` first is the one that gets to set the options. So you don't want them buried away somewhere because someone might accidentally include `windows.h` before including something that includes your wrapper. IMO if you observe that loads of `.cpp` files in your project have identical boilerplate at the start, then it's entirely reasonable to put that in a common header, just don't make it any deeper than that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way some libraries deal with this sort of thing is to let users decide.  Make files like `print/vector.hpp` and `print/set.hpp`, and also make one like `print/all.hpp` (or just `print.hpp`, though that may encourage bad habits).  That last file just #includes all the individual ones, so people who want the "convenience" can have it, and those who want lean-and-mean compilation can have that too.

A common example that works similar to the above is Boost's smart pointer library: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/boost/smart_ptr.hpp

Comment: Thanks for the link. Although I am somewhat familiar with boost, I have never really learnt how they organise their headers, which seems to be an elegant solution to the problem I am facing.

Comment: You're welcome!  Here's another example: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/libs/exception/doc/boost_exception_all_hpp.html

Answer (score 0):

I'd rather ask, whether it is really necessary. You're slowly gravitating into one-class-one-header direction, which will change your #include section into a painfull mess.

If you want to be sure, that you won't mistake a identifier with another, simply use namespaces.

```
namespace PrettyPrint
{
    template<typename T>
    void pretty_print(std::ostream& os, std::vector<T> const& vec);

    template<typename T>
    void pretty_print(std::ostream& os, std::set<T> const& set);

    template<typename T, typename U>
    void pretty_print(std::ostream& os, std::map<T, U> const& map);
}
```

Now, these functions are protected from being mistaken with others and your code remains safe and elegant.

The only drawback I see is, that including long headers will make compilation process a little longer. However, I think, that we're talking about tenths of seconds at most, so if you aren't working on something like old 386, that shouldn't really be a big problem (not to mention precompiled headers, but honestly I did not used them even once).

Comment: How do the namespaces address his question?  (And with regards to the compile times, if he's working on a large project, with hundreds of source files, and each file includes his header, then the difference in build times can be significant.)

Comment: The headers divided into separate files are meant to reduce code bloat. Namespaces reduce it also (you are virtually unable to mistake an identifier for another one from different header file) without requirement to increase count of your include files. I think, that in this particular case with these conditions, problem would be also solved.

Comment: Namespaces don't reduce the size of the *translation unit*, which is what the OP is worried about.

Comment: @Spook How the headers are organized has absolutely no effect on the size of the generated code.  Nor do namespaces.

Answer (score 0):

You may simply try a more generic version:

```
template<class T>
void print_element(std::ostream& os, T const& element)
{
  os << T;
}
template<class Key,class Value>
void print_element(std::ostream& os, std::pair<Key,Value> const& element)
{
  os << '(' << element->first << ',' << element->second << ')';
}

template<typename Container>
void pretty_print(std::ostream& os, Container const& c)
{
   for (auto i: c)
   {
     // print some stuff
     print_element(os, *i);
     // print other stuff
   }
}
```